# What is wrong in my sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query to get the products for today's date only:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products 
        WHERE DATE(date_added) = DATE(NOW()) 
              AND date_available <= NOW()";
```

When run, it returns a product that has a *date_added* field of `"2014-03-19 03:46:11"`, although today is 20th.

---

Added from [*OP's comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524774/what-is-wrong-in-my-sql-statement/22524800?noredirect=1#comment34277163_22524800):

> *sorry for my late comment, `Select NOW()` returns NO (`0`) results – techansaari*

Comment: Is this query running on a server (outside of your network)? What time is it on the server?

Comment: Also even if the server clock *appears* to match your local clock, be sure its time zone is configured correctly.

Comment: check which timezone is going to used.

Comment: running on my local, I have created it yesterday and it returned this one product of 19th, and today also it give the same product while today is 20th

Comment: (It also may be a problem *displaying* the time on the client side; related to incorrect timezone conversion when converting the date to a string; or e.g. it's displaying correct UTC time but you are expecting something else.)

Comment: Is it DATETIME or TIMESTAMP !?!